# How to run a event after write a word in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have try a lot but can't solve . can any one explain me how I'll drive a JavaScript event after write" in " . I mean i wanted to make a div `display:none` to `display:block` after write " in ". that's a auto suggestion issue i've attaching a image the pattern is like that [word] [in] [word]. 
That's will do `onkeyup` event.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried change event of textbox?

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: it's not the issue @HariChaudhary  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS version...

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
var messageBox = document.getElementById('messageBox')

myInput.addEventListener("keyup", checkString);

function checkString() {
    var str = myInput.value;
    // notice whitespace either side of "in" to prevent false positives
    if (str.indexOf(' in ') > -1) { 
        messageBox.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        messageBox.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#messageBox {
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" placeholder="Type here">
    
<div id="messageBox">In was typed</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use input event in jQuery

```
$('#some_text_box').on('input', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // do your stuff
    // split the value by space and check if it contains 'in'
});
```

Comment: @Liam  i think you missed to  see jquery tag in question ?

Comment: you can use  $(this).val(); instead of $('#some_text_box').val()

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery keyup event you can get value which user type in text box while user typing. Then with the use of [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) javascript method you can compare string with `in` word. if match found you can display div otherwise hide that div.

Make sure to use `toLowerCase()` to convert string enter by user in lower case to get perfect match with `in` word. if user enter `in` in uppercase it function works fine.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/1cwd5zxj/)

What is indexOf() method ?

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a
>   specified value in a string.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
>
> Note: The indexOf() method is case sensitive.

```
$('#text').on('keyup', function() {

  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value.toLowerCase().indexOf(' in ') >= 0){
     $('yourdiveselector').show()
  }else{
    $('yourdiveselector').hide()
  }

});
```

Comment: @Liam i think you missed to see jquery tag in question ?

Comment: @Liam  the question is taged in jquery so this is not reason for downvote